# Q: Writing CSV to variable location

Tags: csv, applescript

Very new to AppleScript and have looked for solutions elsewhere unsuccessfully, apologies if I simply missed the answer elsewhere. Thanks for any help.

**Background**: I am using AppleScript to prompt the user for a directory, then create numerous folders in that directory with other prompts.  As prompts are answered, I want to create a CSV that records these answers to prevent repeated answers and also allow the user to terminate the script and return later without losing items stored in lists. CSV seems the simplest way to do this.

**Question**- if I target the CSV to a static path I can successfully create the CSV and record to it. If I create a path from a prompt I receive the error: *Finder got an error: Can’t make alias "Macintosh HD:Users:MyAccount:_Sample_Directory:" into type constant. number -1700 from alias "Macintosh HD:Users:MyAccount:_Sample_Directory:" to constant*

What am I missing?

FYI- using [this as basis for the WriteTo function.](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=36861)

Sample Script:

```
set MyList to {"A", "B", "C"}

tell application "Finder"
    --This Works, but doesn't nest in the variable folder--
    --set CSVFile to (path to desktop as text) & "List.csv" 

    --This is the goal:dynamic directory--
    set ParentFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Select Folder")

    set CSVFile to (path to ParentFolder as string & "List.csv") as POSIX file as alias
end tell

set TheResult to writeto(CSVFile, MyList, list, true)

on writeto(targetFile, theData, dataType, apendData)
    try
        set openFile to open for access file targetFile with write permission
        if apendData is false then set eof of openFile to 0
        write theData to openFile starting at eof as dataType
        close access openFile
        return true

    on error
        try
            close access file targetFile
        end try
        return false

    end try
end writeto
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your script, you do not need to tell application "Finder". So you can remove the tell / end tell.

The error in your script comes from line:

```
set CSVFile to (path to ParentFolder as string & "List.csv") as POSIX file as alias
```

Your sub-routine writeto accepts the targetfile to be in form of string like :

"disk:Users:me:folder:list.csv.

Therefore your first line could be reduced to :

```
set CSVFile to (ParentFolder as string) & "List.csv"
```

Yes, you can write your data in csv. But I am not sure it is the best choice. When you write the list {"A","B","C"} in your file, you are not writing text. So Applescript does a conversion from list to text. In this example the result is "listutxtAutxtButxtC". It depends what you want to do with that file, but to make it readable, it is better to write text in text file. You can do this by looping through all items of MyList to write each one as a text:

```
repeat with x in MyList
    set TheResult to writeto(CSVFile, x, list, true)
end repeat
```

In above example, I still use datatype = list, instead of text. It does not matter because the subroutine does not use that parameter.I guess this is for future use.

Still it may not give you the result you're looking for. The text in file will be "ABC". To avoid this, I suggest you to add a return (or a tab) for each data you write in the file. Do to so, change the line in the writeto sub-routine :

```
write (theData & return) to openFile starting at eof as dataType
```

Then your cvs file will be

```
A
B
C
```

Which is easy to read.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! This is super helpful.  Not entirely sure if CSV is the best solution either, but it's a starting point.  Ultimately the user is entering a reference number, SKU, variants, and possibly date of entry.  The SKUs and variants need to be sent on for record keeping so CSV seemed a readable format, but would this be better served with AppleScript records? Would records complicate the usability of CSVs?

Comment: You said, "When you write the list {"A","B","C"} in your file, you are not writing text. So AppleScript does a conversion from list to text. In this example the result is "listutxtAutxtButxtC"." There appears to be some contradiction between the sentences I've quoted. While "listutxtAutxtButxtC" is in appearance a textual string, in reality what's written to the file actually is not what you've shown! AppleScript, in this example, writes a binary file, **not** "does a conversion from list to text", and wherever you copied that string from is not accurate as to the actual contents of the file.

Comment: If it were, then looking at, e.g. "List.csv" at the hex level the files contents would be `6C697374757478744175747874427574787443` however in reality the files contents is actually `6C69737400000003757478740000000200417574787400000002004275747874000000020043` and this "listutxtAutxtButxtC" text string is not the true contents of the binary file created by AppleScript. "listutxtAutxtButxtC" is an obfuscated representation of the files actual contents. If you read the contents of the file back into a variable in the script as a list, it's really no different then `set MyList to {"A", "B", "C"}`.

Comment: You also said, "In above example, I still use datatype = list, instead of text. It does not matter because the subroutine does not use that parameter.I guess this is for future use.", where in fact the `writeto` _handler_ is in fact using that parameter in "`write theData to openFile starting at eof as dataType`". IMO I see a lot wrong with how this answer is currently written and I'd suggest you clean/clear up some of it. Also, lets refrain from the use of .cvs or CVS file when in fact none of the code in the question or this answer actually produces a _comma separated value_ file.

Comment: @Ian : goods that it helps. if you want to keep it simple and readable, yes you can use cvs, but then write the strings value of all your variables, separate by something (return, semicolon,...) to make it easier to read. If you do not need human read, just build a record with all your data (the ref, SKU, date of entry,..). Applescript read function using exactly same record will be able to read it.

Comment: @user3439894:Applescript converts from a variable list into a list of characters. Of course that list of characters could always be viewed as a string, still Applescript converts it by adding 'list' and 'utxt' before each item. Yes, if you read that "string" back in Applescript, it does also the reverse conversion. That's why Applescript is so easy : it always try to coerce to relevant data type. Also you're right, I miss the 'as datatype' in the handler. Sorry. Still the key question is what Ian wants to do with that cvs file. Answer should defined the datatype and file format.

Comment: Given the AppleScript `list` `{"A", "B", "C"}`, the 3 items of the list are already text alpha characters so there is no conversion to text when written to a file as a `list` however, for the sake of argument, then this `list` `{1, "B", 3}` by your wrong assumption would be "listutxt1utxtButxt3" but if you look at the file in e.g. TextEdit, which is not the appropriate for a binary file, it shows as "listlongutxtBlong". Note that `1` and `3` are not there, only `B`! As I mentioned earlier, "listutxtAutxtButxtC" is an obfuscated representation of the files actual contents.

Comment: There is no conversion to text when written as a `list`, the `list` in this case is written as a `list`, not text! "listutxtAutxtButxtC" is not the entire contents of the file, nor is "listlongutxtBlong" for `{1, "B", 3}` written as a `list`! Look at the resultant file in a Hex Editor, its contents is not only either of the two examples strings! Since AppleScript writes the `list` as a `list` in this case the resultant file is a binary file that does contain text strings, as most binary files do but what you see in e.g. Finder/TextEdit is not the files actual contents!

Comment: [Here is a link to a screen shot of the files in a Hex Editor](https://imgur.com/a/6KBDFKO) and as you can plainly see there are gaps between the data type markers and their value as well as additional information that is not show in either "listutxtAutxtButxtC" or "listlongutxtBlong" which is not an accurate representation of what's in either file. When looking at binary files, you need to look at them with e.g. a Hex Editor, not Finders Preview or TextEdit (as wrong examples) to see the real and actual contents of a AppleScript `list` written to a file as a `list`!

Comment: I'll have to re-read this a few times to wrap my brain around it. In reality, 'myList' begins as '{}' and fills as the user enters text into prompts. End goal is to prevent a SKU/string being entered twice.  There are two prompts which are linked so an AS record would be beneficial, but the list of SKUs needs to be entered into an Excel sheet later. That and comparing a property from a list of records against a string is ahead of me right now. This may evolve into parallel items, Record List and CSV for function and readability. Not sure how this impacts the 'datatype' of 'onWrite'.

Comment: how many SKU do you plan to have 10, 100, 100000 ? if small number, then simple file cvs, or text should be more than enough. if very high number, then you may have to use a small/basic data base. if your file only contains the list of SKU for which you just want to know if already in the list, you can use a simple text file and in AS call a unix command (find or grep) on that file.

Comment: Each set/day could have up to 50 SKU’s with as many as 250 folders created in a day from all the variants. Not bad locally, but I’d love to see this grow that multiple sets are all compiling a list which would be 50,000+ per quarter. We’re currently manually doing this via Excel/Sheets. 250 isolated items in a CSV seems very manageable, though if there’s a better option for future growth it’s certainly worth considering.

Comment: For 50,000+ records, you can still use Excel, assuming it is for a single user (if multiple users, then small database like SQL Lite). I just have part of your requirements, but I think your issue is not to manage cvs (you have Excel directly), but to allow automatic creation of 250 folders based on values of cells in Excel. Then may be using Excel with VBA macro which does the folder creation (VBA can call AS) should be a better approach...?